# How to install XCMS package in R

Tags: r

When I am trying installing `XCMS` using command `install.packages("xcms")`
I got the following warning:

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/pma/Desktop/R3/packages’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>    package ‘xcms’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4).

I can't find any reference to this problem in the forums,
 can anyone suggest a solution? Thank you!
I should add that I am working in corporate environment cannot install updated versions than 3.4.4. I have already tried installing  3.3 version it did not work. I am using windows 10, R Studio Version 1.1.456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xcms is a package which is available through Bioconductor. Please see the website of Bioconductor on how to install [xcms](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/xcms.html).

Comment: Thanks ,it installed.